# Exactness and tensor product questions based on $A/\mathfrak{a} \otimes M \cong M/\mathfrak{a} M$

Tags: tensor-products, exact-sequence

My brain has refused to understand tensor products for a very long time, so I wrote up a solution for this classical exercise accompanied by my elementary questions.

**Exercise:** Let $A$ be a ring, $\mathfrak{a}$ an ideal, $M$ an $A$-module. Show that $A/\mathfrak{a} \otimes M \cong M/\mathfrak{a} M$.

**Proof:**
Consider long exact sequence

$$ 0 \rightarrow \mathfrak{a} \rightarrow A \rightarrow A/\mathfrak{a} \rightarrow 0 $$

It is exact, because it is exact at

- $\mathfrak{a}$, since the image of $0$ is mapped to $0$ in $A$ under inclusion.
- $A$, since $\mathfrak{a}$ is by definition the kernel of the quotient map $A\rightarrow A/\mathfrak{a}$,
- $A/\mathfrak{a}$, since the quotient map is surjective and everything is mapped to $0$.

If we tensor this sequence with $M$, we get

$$ 0\otimes M\rightarrow \mathfrak{a}\otimes M \rightarrow A\otimes M \rightarrow A/\mathfrak{a}\otimes M \rightarrow 0\otimes M$$

- We can say $0\otimes M = 0$, because $\forall m \in M : B(0,m) = B(0+0,m) = 2B(0,m) \implies B(0,m) = 0$. And since all elements of $0 \otimes M$ are linear combinations of pure tensors $0\otimes m$, they are all equal to $0$? There is probably a simpler way to see this...
- Next $\mathfrak{a}\otimes M = \mathfrak{a}M$ because $\forall a \in\mathfrak{a}: B(a,m)=aB(1,m)=B(1,am)$, so $\mathfrak{a}\otimes M \cong 1\otimes \mathfrak{a}M \cong \mathfrak{a}M$?
- Now $A\otimes M \cong M$ by the same principle as above. In my mind, if $M$ is an $A$-module, then it contains a copy of $A$ by definition if we consider scalar multiplication of $A \times \{1\} \rightarrow M$, so tensoring $M$ by something that is already part of $M$ does nothing?

Since tensor product is right-exact, they are supposed to preserve the exactness of the right part of the diagram, implying that this diagram is exact...?

$$\mathfrak{a} M \rightarrow M \rightarrow A/\mathfrak{a}\otimes M \rightarrow 0$$

I'm confused, if I have an exact long sequence and tensor it, how do I understand what part of the sequence stays exact? Is it enough to exclude the left-most object from the diagram? What if this object isn't zero?

Assuming this diagram is exact, the map $M \rightarrow A/\mathfrak{a}\otimes M$ is surjective and $ker(M \rightarrow A/\mathfrak{a}\otimes M) = \mathfrak{a} M$, so it follows from isomorphism theorems that $A/\mathfrak{a}\otimes M = M/ker(M \rightarrow A/\mathfrak{a}\otimes M) = M/\mathfrak{a} M$ and we're done. Or are we? In this step I am confused by the silent treatment of the map $M \rightarrow A/\mathfrak{a}\otimes M$, so I tried to calculate it by hand.

What exactly is the map $M\rightarrow A/\mathfrak{a}\otimes M$? It comes from the quotient map $A \rightarrow A/\mathfrak{a}, a \mapsto a +\mathfrak{a}$ which was then tensored with $M$ and it became $(a\otimes m) \mapsto (a+\mathfrak{a}\otimes m)$. We've shown that it is the same as $(a\otimes m) \mapsto (1\otimes am)\mapsto (1\otimes am + \mathfrak{a}m)$, so the kernel is $\mathfrak{a}m$ and the final answer is $A/\mathfrak{a} \otimes M \cong M/\mathfrak{a}M$...?

Comment: I think that if you are not very comfortable with tensor products it might help to try to solve the problem using elements and defining the isomorphism explicitly. You have the multiplication map $A \otimes_A M \to M$, and you have to think why the same formula gives a well-defined map $A/\mathfrak{a} \otimes_A M \to M/\mathfrak{a}M$, and prove directly that this is an isomorphism.

Comment: You have to be careful with moving the elements around in the tensor product: you write $B(a,m) = aB(1,m)$ but $1$ is not in general an element of the ideal $\mathfrak{a}$, so your "proof" that $\mathfrak{a} \otimes M \cong \mathfrak{a}M$ is incorrect. In fact this is false in general, and this is why the tensor product is only right exact. What is true is that $\mathfrak{a}M$ is the image of $\mathfrak{a} \otimes M$ under the multiplication morphism (by definition).

Comment: @EduardodeLorenzo good catch, thank you! I'll try out your suggestion.